# How to apply a <forcedType> to a stored function in jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, code-generation, jooq, stored-functions

A common question among jOOQ users is how a [`<forcedType>`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/) can be applied to a stored function return type in the code generator. The manual specifies that `<includeExpression>` matches qualified or unqualified identifiers, so given this HSQLDB function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION stored_functions.f_1 (p_i int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN ATOMIC
  RETURN p_i;
END
```

The parameter of the function can be forced to `String` using:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <userType>java.lang.String</userType>
  <converter>
    org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(Integer.class, String.class, Object::toString, Integer::valueOf)
  </converter>
  <includeExpression>(?i:f_1\.p_i)</includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

This produces the following `Parameter` specification:

```java
/**
 * The parameter <code>STORED_FUNCTIONS.F_1.P_I</code>.
 */
public static final Parameter<String> P_I = Internal.createParameter(
  "P_I", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER, false, false, 
  org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(Integer.class, String.class, Object::toString, Integer::valueOf)
);
```

How to do the same for the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a synthetic parameter name that can be used. It's called `return_value`, which is also the name of the generated [`Parameter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Parameter.html) literal.

The following specification will apply the same converter to both the `P_I` parameter and `RETURN_VALUE`:

```xml
<forcedType>
  <userType>java.lang.String</userType>
  <converter>
    org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(Integer.class, String.class, Object::toString, Integer::valueOf)
  </converter>
  <includeExpression>(?i:f_1\.p_i|return_value)</includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

This produces the following `Parameter` specifications:

```java
/**
 * The parameter <code>STORED_FUNCTIONS.F_1.RETURN_VALUE</code>.
 */
public static final Parameter<String> RETURN_VALUE = Internal.createParameter(
  "RETURN_VALUE", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER, false, false, 
  org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(Integer.class, String.class, Object::toString, Integer::valueOf)
);

/**
 * The parameter <code>STORED_FUNCTIONS.F_1.P_I</code>.
 */
public static final Parameter<String> P_I = Internal.createParameter(
  "P_I", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER, false, false, 
  org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(Integer.class, String.class, Object::toString, Integer::valueOf)
);
```

Comment: What if PARAMTER type and RETURN_VALUE type there are DIFFERENT types (e.g. PARAMETER type is of `org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BIGINT` type and RETURN_VALUE is of type `org.jooq.JSON`)? BTW, PL flavor is PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Then you create two `<forcedType>` elements.

Comment: Could you please provide an example (**different types** of **return value** and **input parameter** of **stored function**) in your answer? I've tried to implement it and it didn't work...probably I'm doing something wrong, so such an example would be of a great help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've tried to that (to create two `<forcedType>` elements), but I've ran into problems and therefore I created another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62601302/6805866). Please take a look.