# How to properly format generated routine result of JSON type by using formatJSON(JSONFormat) in jOOQ?

Tags: java, arrays, json, plpgsql, jooq

I'm having issue with properly formatting my JSON result when querying **generated Routine** by using jOOQ code generator. I'm trying to perform SELECT-clause on my `get_all_orders()` method defined in **PL/pgSQL** (mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62601302/6805866) question) which returns result of `json` type. This is my code for performing jOOQ-fied query:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
Result<Record1<String>> resultR1S = create.select(Routines.getAllOrders()).fetch();
final String strResultFinal = resultR1S.formatJSON(
    new JSONFormat().header(false).recordFormat(RecordFormat.ARRAY)
);
```

...and this is output I get on console (bit truncated at the end because result output is waaaay too long to fit in):

```
[["{\"orders\" : [{\"order_id\" : 1, \"total_price\" : 29.98, \"order_date\" : \"2019-08-22T10:06:33\", \"user\" : {\"user_id\" : 1, \"username\" : \"test\"}, \"order_items\" : [{\"order_item_id\" : 1, \"amount\" : 1, \"book\" : {\"book_id\" : 1, \"title\" : \"Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone\", \"price\" : 29.98, \"amount\" : 400, \"is_deleted\" : false, \"authors\" : [{\"author_id\":4,\"first_name\":\"JK\",\"last_name\":\"Rowling\"}], \"categories\" : [{\"category_id\":2,\"name\":\"Lyric\",\"is_deleted\":false}]}, \"order_id\" : 1, \"total_order_item_price\" : 29.98}]}, {...}"]]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get rid off **double angle brackets (at beginning and end of output)** and **backslash characters** so it looks something like this:

```
{"orders" : [{"order_id" : 1, "total_price" : 29.98, "order_date" : "2019-08-22T10:06:33", "user\" : {"user_id" : 1, "username\" : "test"}, ...]}
```

I can't seem to find a fix for this, so is there any proper way to achieve that by using formatJSON(JSONFormat) method...or some other method?
Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research for appropriate JSON library to achieve what I want I've decided to do it this way (until more convenient method is available in jOOQ **3.13.1**):

```
String strResultFinal = resultR1S.formatJSON(
        new JSONFormat()
        .header(false)
        .recordFormat(RecordFormat.ARRAY)
);
final String fixedJSONString = strResultFinal
        .substring(3, strResultFinal.length() - 3)
        .replaceAll("\\\\n", "") // for some reason '\n' is being part of String (I presume for new row) and needs to be removed for proper JSON format... 
        .replaceAll("\\\\", ""); //...as well as escaping backslash character
```

Now I get desired JSON format like this (BTW, it's trimmed :) ):

```
{"orders" : [{"order_id" : 1, "total_price" : 29.98, "order_date" : "2019-08-22T10:06:33", "user" : {"user_id" : 1, "username" : "test"}, ..}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing feature to allow for combining the use of `JSON`/`JSONB` columns with [`Result.formatJSON()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Formattable.html#formatJSON()) (or of `XML` columns with [`Result.formatXML()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Formattable.html#formatXML())): https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10361

As a workaround, you'll have to do this work yourself, manually, and avoid the `formatJSON()` method.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you for quick response. Are there any other libraries that you would recommend for doing this kind of JSON formatting (removing unnecessary angle brackets and backslashes)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NikolaS: I wouldn't fix wrong output. I would make sure the output is correct from the beginning.

Comment: I agree, but are there any suitable methods in jOOQ to achieve such a thing? Right now I'm trying to use String class methods such as `replaceAll()` and `substring()` in order to fix the messed up output as a temporary solution (as I can't seem to find another-better way).

Comment: I've posted (temporary) solution for my use-case as answer to my question. If you have something to add up/correct please let me know. Any advice/suggestion is welcome. :)

Comment: No, there are no suitable methods for this in jOOQ because 1) there was a missing feature, which is now implemented for jOOQ 3.14, and 2) why would there be a method for doing something that is not recommended? :) I mean, of course, you can use arbitrary JDK methods to patch strings...

Comment: Can you please clarify what is NOT recommended? I'm kind of confused now (since you said that **missing feature** has been implemented in jOOQ 3.14)... :)

Comment: @NikolaS: As I said. I wouldn't fix wrong output. Never. Not with jOOQ, not with anything else. Formatted data is lost data. Better write some custom logic that formats the raw data correctly. At least, that's my opinion.